# Locked Out of FreeBSD

Tags: shell, freebsd, login

So I'm upgrading from FreeBSD 7.2 to FreeBSD 8.0 and after a while I get to the part where you have to rebuild all 3rd party applications (stuff from the ports tree or those compiled from source).  I do that, invoke `freebsd-update install` one last time and reboot.

It turns out that bash requires an old libncurses version which is fine except that I completely forgot about rebuilding bash!  Furthermore, I did not heed the usual warning on keeping root's default shell sh.  (Like what can happen, right? Ha!)  So I've learned a lesson about heeding warnings.

Now, however, I need to learn if I'm screwed or if there's some way to get out of this.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a live CD to boot with, then chroot into your FreeBSD's /, and then either set root shell to sh or rebuild bash?

Comment: Good idea; definitely worth a try.  Why not put it as an answer and get some rep?  If it works, you'll get 25 from me alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you boot in single user mode? It asks for the shell path and defaults to /bin/sh.